# SQL: How do you only select the groups where any given group has all of the values given?

Tags: sql, mariadb

Given a table like this(which I got to through using joins and wheres)

```
| post_id | comment_id |
|    1    |     100    |
|    1    |     101    |
|    1    |     102    |
| .  2 .  | .   100 .  |
| .  3 .  | .   101 .  |
| .  3 .  | .   102 .  |
```

and given a list of one or more comment ids.

(100, 101)

Only find the posts where the post does not have **ALL** of the given comment_ids

---

So, with this table and a comment_id list of (100,101), it should return post id (2,3) because post ids 2 and 3 do not have both comments 100 and 101.

With comment_id list of (101), it should return post id (2).

With a comment_id of (103), it should return post_id (1,2,3) because these posts do not have comment 103(which does not exist).

---

Edit:

I was able to get it working with just one comment_id inputted with this code.

```sql
select post_id
from table_name
group by post_id
having count(*) = sum( comment_id not in (100) )
```

I added the 'not' from Gordon's answer to get it to work, but when I use more than one comment like:

```sql
having count(*) = sum( comment_id not in (100, 102) )
```

then it brings back all of the post_ids (1,2,3). It should only be bringing back post_id (2,3). Post_id 1 has both 100 and 102 comment_ids so it cannot be included in the query.

How do I get it to accept multiple comment ids?

Comment: your query seems to be complicated at first you are saying return post which are not having all comment_ids and in the explanation you are saying via comment_ids post output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select post_id
from t
group by post_id
having count(*) = sum( comment_id in (2, 3) );
```

This assumes that the table does not have duplicates.  If that is a possibility, then:

```
having count(distinct comment_id) = count(distinct case when comment_id in (2, 3) then comment_id end)
```

EDIT:

I must've misread the original post.  I thought you wanted the ones that had all the comments.  So you want:

```
select post_id
from t
group by post_id
having 2 <> sum( comment_id in (2, 3) );
```

Comment: It seems like it's not working for me. I might have explained the problem incorrectly. I changed it so it works for only one comment_id input, but can't seem to get it working for multiple comments. I'll edit my original question.

Comment: @DanielSunYang . . . I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1):

As by your query, every post must have 3 comment_id's atmost. Accordingly, below is the query to find with not having the same

```
        SELECT POST_ID FROM TABLE
           GROUP BY POST_ID HAVING 
       COUNT(Distinct COMMENT_ID) <3
```